# How do I access my website created through route53 with an elastic load balancer?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I've just registered my website kashpress20.com (a wordpress website) created created via instances,etc. I put my instances behind an Elastic Load Balancer.

The ELB's DNS name works just fine. WordPressALB-936487591.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

I tied the ELB to the alias type on my route 53. However, when I try to access the website online i get:

www.kashpress20.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Also when I use https://dnschecker.org/#A/kashpress20.com to check my website availability, its not available anywhere

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your domain isn't registered with the com. name servers, so I can't even find any NS records for your domain. Are you sure you've configured Route53 with your registrar?